# Query key values in a json column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table "jobs" with  one of the columns called "check_list" ( varchar(max) that has JSON values, an example value would be

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "name":"machine 1",
         "state":"",
         "comment":"",
         "isReleaseToProductionCheck":true,
         "mnachine_id":10
      },
      {
         "name":"machine 2",
         "state":"",
         "comment":"",
         "isReleaseToProductionCheck":true,
         "machine_id":12
      }
   ]
}
```

Now how would I write a SQL query to only return the rows where the column "check_list" has items[machine_id] = 12

Comment: what type is columns called "check_list" ?

Comment: So what have you tried? Aside... `items` is a JSON array and so is indexed by number, i.e.: you can't index by name `machine_id` as if it were a Dictionary or hashmap.

Comment: you can use **LIKE %%** for this SELECT * FROM jobs
WHERE check_list LIKE '%"machine_id":12%'

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 0):

In the end after some trial and error this was the solution that worked for me. I had to add the ISJSON check because some of the older data was invalid

```
WITH jobs (id, workorder, selectedMachine) AS(
  SELECT 
    [id], 
    [workorder], 
    (
      select 
        * 
      from 
        openjson(check_list, '$.items') with (machine_id int '$.machine_id') 
      where 
        machine_id = 12
    ) as selectedMachine 
  FROM 
    engineering_job_schedule 
  WHERE 
    ISJSON(check_list) > 0
) 
Select 
  * 
from 
  jobs 
where 
  selectedMachine = 12
```